# Call method of new activity from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

There are two Activities..
1. Open SecondActivity from MainActivity
2. When event comes into MainActivity, call testMethod of SecondActivity

But how to do call this testMethod?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements someListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Launch SecondActivity here!!
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ID_PlayerActivity);
    }

    //trigger by JNI, it's in the other thread, not main thread.
    void onEventCome() {
        //How to call testMethod() in SecondActivity?
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    void testMethod() {
        //execute something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call the method in secondActivity? You can just separate it to another class and make it static like this... `MyProjUtils.testMethod();`

Comment: Because there are two threads here
Main thread is in SecondActivity, and the other thread will trigger event to MainActivity.
When event arrival, MainActivity will execute testMethod in SecondActivity..

Comment: You can put testmethod() in an interface and implement it in Second Activity then create a `public static Context me; public void onCreate(){me = SecondActivity.this;} public Context getInstance() {return me;}` and to use this: `((SecondActivity.getInstance())Listener).testMethod();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the SecondActivity, your MainActivity becomes inactive. I don't believe it is a good idea to call some activity method from other inactive/stopped activity.

I suggest to use [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Create a global long-lived object like EventProducer and register all activities as observer. So your EventProducer can inform all Activities about new event.

Example:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements MyEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventProducer.instance().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventProducer.instance().unregister(this);
    }

    void testMethod(){
        //just doit
    }

    @Override
    void onMyEventCome() {
        testMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need an event aware listener that will capture such an event happening. Your class seems ill equipped to do so.

Since you have a valid question, here goes:

```
void onEventCome() {
    SecondActivity secondActivity = new SecondActivity();
    secondActivity.testMethod();
}
```

Comment: SecondActivity has launch by onCreate() in MainActivity..
If it new a SecondActivity again in onEventCome, it's OK?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways.
For eg: 
Create the method as static and use class name and call it.

```
public static void onEventCome() {

}
```

In MainActivity:

```
MainActivity.onEventCome();
```

This is one method. Another method is create an object for MainActivity.

```
public void onEventCome() {

}
```

MainActivity main;

```
main = new MainActivity();
main.onEventCome();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a content view for your second activity. If you don't need to see the operation happen, you could remove your

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ID_PlayerActivity);
```

remove `extends Activity` in `SecondActivity` and add a constructor `public SecondActivity(Context context)` and invoke the test method from your first activity like @Dragan example:

```
void onEventCome() {
    SecondActivity secondActivity = new SecondActivity(MainActivity.this);
    secondActivity.testMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
There are some UI content in SecondActivity, it cannot remove Activity attribute...